# Cannot delete URLs with Chrome's history API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I am making a Chrome extension to remove certain URLs from my history, using [Chrome's history API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html). Here is the code so far:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form'),
        query = document.getElementById('query')
    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // alert(chrome.history)            // [object Object]
        // alert(chrome.history.deleteUrl)  // function () { [native code] }
        // alert(query.value)               // whatever I typed
        chrome.history.deleteUrl(query.value)
    }
    query.focus()
})
```

(`form` is the form in my popup, and `query` is the text box in which you can type.)

As you can see from the three `alert`s, the variables are fine. However, the code isn't actually removing the URL from the history. When I check (in `chrome://history/`), the URLs are still there.

Here is my `manifest.json`, if that matters:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "UnVizit",
    "description": "Mark a link as \"not visited\" easily",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "history"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I am using version `28.0.1500.95 (Official Build 213514) m` of Chrome.

Comment: Hint: When your form gets submitted, the page is unloaded unless you `return true;` or call `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: @RobW Thanks, trying that now... EDIT: still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @RobW I tried it and it still didn't work. I edited the line into my question though, to show that that is not the problem.

Comment: @Doorkob Inspect the popup. You'll see an error about a mismatching API call. [`chrome.history.deleteUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl) expects an object with key `url`, not a string.

Comment: @RobW Ah, I was just hitting F12 and saw no errors. I will try the object now.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup

Comment: @RobW Alright, thanks for that. That will help with debugging a lot. The object worked! If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a string to the [`chrome.history.deleteUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-deleteUrl) method, but an object with key url. If you [inspect your popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup), you would see the following error:

> Error: Invocation of form history.deleteUrl(string) doesn't match definition history.deleteUrl(object details, optional function callback)

In summary, change

```js
chrome.history.deleteUrl(query.value)
```

to

```js
chrome.history.deleteUrl({ url: query.value });
```